# How to Input Keys using vbscript Into Batch

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Is there a way to make a VBScript input alt+enter to a batch file that has already been executed? (batch file>VBScript(input alt+enter)>batch file)

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this for?

Comment: total guess at what you are trying to do.. but maybe sendkeys would help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx